# in spark sql getting problem while joining two dataframes . pleses solve my problem

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes ,the first data frame 10 columns , (street ,state(rows are CA ,US).etc) and 2 nd data frame  two columns (state and state full name) I want to join these two data frames using state but I don't want join  state columns in that replace state with full name.

I have used,

`tranDF.join(stateDF,tranDF("state")===stateDF("state"),"inner").show(false)`

my required columns are

```
street city state_NM beds ...etc
```

I want one columns from stateDF that should replace state column from tranDF please any one answer my question

Comment: Here are some suggestions while posting. 1) Question might have clear data examples (you can post sample csv or data frame ) with out which its difficult to give producible  answer. 2) wording and sentences should be clear and should reveal your intention of what you are asking. 3) avoid spelling mistakes 4) Dont be hurry in posting a question review your question as if you are other person who is reading the question. with these you will get better answer to your questions. keep in mind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if below code works for you,

```
joinDF= (tranDF.alias("a").join(stateDF.alias("b"), 
         col("a.state") == col("b.state") ,how='inner') 
         .drop(col("a.state")).drop(col("b.state")))
```

Comment: I am not aware whether any keyword like this `,how=`  exists in spark  API

Comment: this one is available in pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

The below way should work...

```
  trandf.join(statedf,trandf("state")===statedf("state"),"inner")
    .selectExpr("trans.street", "trans.city", "state.statefullname", "trans.type")  
    .show(false)
```

Explanation : create alias for each df as '`trans`' and '`state`' 
after inner join  select the columns only you wanted and that are relavent. using `select` or `selectExpr`  as shown below.

---

Full example in spark with scala with walmart data..

```
package examples

import examples.JoinDemo.trandf
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object JoinDemo extends App {
  val logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org")
  logger.setLevel(Level.WARN)

  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("JoinDemo").master("local").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val mycsvdata = """
    |"statefullname","state"
    |"Alabama","AL"
    |"Alaska","AK"
    |"Arizona","AZ"
    |"Arkansas","AR"
    |"California","CA"
    |"Colorado","CO"
    |"Connecticut","CT"
    |"Delaware","DE"
    |"District of Columbia","DC"
    |"Florida","FL"
    |"Georgia","GA"
    |"Hawaii","HI"
    |"Idaho","ID"
    |"Illinois","IL"
    |"Indiana","IN"
    |"Iowa","IA"
    |"Kansas","KS"
    |"Kentucky","KY"
    |"Louisiana","LA"
    |"Maine","ME"
    |"Montana","MT"
    |"Nebraska","NE"
    |"Nevada","NV"
    |"New Hampshire","NH"
    |"New Jersey","NJ"
    |"New Mexico","NM"
    |"New York","NY"
    |"North Carolina","NC"
    |"North Dakota","ND"
    |"Ohio","OH"
    |"Oklahoma","OK"
    |"Oregon","OR"
    |"Maryland","MD"
    |"Massachusetts","MA"
    |"Michigan","MI"
    |"Minnesota","MN"
    |"Mississippi","MS"
    |"Missouri","MO"
    |"Pennsylvania","PA"
    |"Rhode Island","RI"
    |"South Carolina","SC"
    |"South Dakota","SD"
    |"Tennessee","TN"
    |"Texas","TX"
    |"Utah","UT"
    |"Vermont","VT"
    |"Virginia","VA"
    |"Washington","WA"
    |"West Virginia","WV"
    |"Wisconsin","WI"
    |"Wyoming","WY"
  """.stripMargin.lines.toList.toDS
val mycsvdata1 =
  """
    |"opendate","street","city","state","long","lat","type"
    |1962-03-01,"5801 SW Regional Airport Blvd","Bentonville","AR",-94.239816,36.350885,"DistributionCenter"
    |1962-07-01,"2110 WEST WALNUT","Rogers","AR",-94.07141,36.342235,"SuperCenter"
    |1964-08-01,"1417 HWY 62/65 N","Harrison","AR",-93.09345,36.236984,"SuperCenter"
    |1965-08-01,"2901 HWY 412 EAST","Siloam Springs","AR",-94.50208,36.179905,"SuperCenter"
    |1967-10-01,"3801 CAMP ROBINSON RD.","North Little Rock","AR",-92.30229,34.813269,"Wal-MartStore"
    |1967-10-01,"1621 NORTH BUSINESS 9","Morrilton","AR",-92.75858,35.156491,"SuperCenter"
    |1968-03-01,"1303 SOUTH MAIN","Sikeston","MO",-89.58355,36.891163,"SuperCenter"
    |1968-03-01,"65 WAL-MART DRIVE","Mountain Home","AR",-92.35781,36.329026,"SuperCenter"
    |1968-07-01,"2020 SOUTH MUSKOGEE","Tahlequah","OK",-94.97185,35.923658,"SuperCenter"
    |1968-07-01,"1500 LYNN RIGGS BLVD","Claremore","OK",-95.61192,36.327143,"SuperCenter"
    |1968-11-01,"2705 GRAND AVE","Carthage","MO",-94.31164,37.168985,"SuperCenter"
    |1969-04-01,"1800 S JEFFERSON","Lebanon","MO",-92.64733,37.678528,"SuperCenter"
    |1969-04-01,"2214 FAYETTEVILLE RD","Van Buren","AR",-94.34581,35.456536,"SuperCenter"
    |1969-05-01,"1310 PREACHER RD/HGWY 160","West Plains","MO",-91.87408,36.719145,"SuperCenter"
    |1969-05-01,"3200 LUSK DRIVE","Neosho","MO",-94.39016,36.86429,"SuperCenter"
    |1969-11-01,"2500 MALCOLM ST/HWY 67 NORTH","Newport","AR",-91.24695,35.586065,"Wal-MartStore"
    |1970-03-01,"185 ST ROBERT BLVD","St. Robert","MO",-92.135741,37.827415,"SuperCenter"
    |1970-10-01,"1712 EAST OHIO","Clinton","MO",-93.76042,38.364214,"SuperCenter"
    |1970-10-01,"4901 SO. MILL ROAD","Pryor","OK",-95.30295,36.294174,"SuperCenter"
    |1970-11-01,"1201 N SERVICE ROAD EAST","Ruston","LA",-92.64696,32.52476,"SuperCenter"
    |1970-11-01,"3450 S. 4TH TRAFFICWAY","Leavenworth","KS",-94.93555,39.298776,"Wal-MartStore"
    |1971-02-01,"4820 SO. CLARK ST","Mexico","MO",-91.88404,39.179316,"SuperCenter"
    |1971-02-01,"1101 HWY 32 WEST","Salem","MO",-91.51423,37.630896,"SuperCenter"
    |1971-04-01,"2000 JOHN HARDEN DR","Jacksonville","AR",-92.12244,34.879419,"SuperCenter"
    |1971-05-01,"2415 N.W. MAIN ST","Miami","OK",-94.87142,36.880746,"SuperCenter"
    |1971-06-01,"3108 N BROADWAY","Poteau","OK",-94.61829,35.052793,"SuperCenter"
    |1971-06-01,"2050 WEST HWY 76","Branson","MO",-93.25668,36.64417,"Wal-MartStore"
    |1971-06-01,"1710 SO. 4TH ST","Nashville","AR",-93.85214,33.985613,"SuperCenter"
    |1971-08-01,"724 STADIUM WEST BLVD","Jefferson City","MO",-92.25329,38.568287,"SuperCenter"
    |1971-09-01,"701 WALTON DRIVE","Farmington","MO",-90.41404,37.779206,"SuperCenter"
    |1971-10-01,"101 EAST BLUEMONT AVENUE","Manhattan","KS",-96.56932,39.184986,"SuperCenter"
    |1971-11-01,"2025 BUS. HWY 60 WEST","Dexter","MO",-89.97428,36.784453,"SuperCenter"
    |1971-11-01,"2250 LINCOLN AVENUE","Nevada","MO",-94.35075,37.838563,"SuperCenter"
    |1971-11-01,"2802 WEST KINGS HIGHWAY","Paragould","AR",-90.5102,36.065711,"SuperCenter"
    |1971-11-01,"1301 HWY 24 EAST","Moberly","MO",-92.4344,39.420353,"SuperCenter"
    |1971-12-09,"1907 SE WASHINGTON ST.","Idabel","OK",-94.83154,33.883578,"SuperCenter"
    |1972-02-01,"1802 SOUTH BUSINESS HWY 54","Eldon","MO",-92.58395,38.311355,"Wal-MartStore"
    |1972-03-01,"2400 SOUTH MAIN","Fort Scott","KS",-94.73389,37.823295,"Wal-MartStore"
    |1972-05-01,"1155 HWY 65 NORTH","Conway","AR",-92.43401,35.075467,"SuperCenter"
    |1972-05-01,"4000 GREEN COUNTRY RD","Bartlesville","OK",-95.92404,36.733398,"SuperCenter"
  """.stripMargin.lines.toList.toDS
  val trandf: DataFrame = spark.read.option("header", true)
    .option("sep", ",")
    .option("inferSchema", true)
    .csv(mycsvdata1).as("trans")

  val statedf: DataFrame = spark.read.option("header", true)
    .option("sep", ",")
    .option("inferSchema", true)
    .csv(mycsvdata).as("state")

  trandf.join(statedf,trandf("state")===statedf("state"),"inner")
    .selectExpr("trans.street", "trans.city", "state.statefullname", "trans.type") // you want only columns from state df
    .show(false)

}
```

Result :

```
+--------------------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
|street                    |city          |statefullname|type         |
+--------------------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
|1201 N SERVICE ROAD EAST  |Ruston        |Louisiana    |SuperCenter  |
|1303 SOUTH MAIN           |Sikeston      |Missouri     |SuperCenter  |
|2705 GRAND AVE            |Carthage      |Missouri     |SuperCenter  |
|1800 S JEFFERSON          |Lebanon       |Missouri     |SuperCenter  |
|1310 PREACHER RD/HGWY 160 |West Plains   |Missouri     |SuperCenter  |
|3200 LUSK DRIVE           |Neosho        |Missouri     |SuperCenter  |
|185 ST ROBERT BLVD        |St. Robert    |Missouri     |SuperCenter  |
|1712 EAST OHIO            |Clinton       |Missouri     |SuperCenter  |
|4820 SO. CLARK ST         |Mexico        |Missouri     |SuperCenter  |
|1101 HWY 32 WEST          |Salem         |Missouri     |SuperCenter  |
|2050 WEST HWY 76          |Branson       |Missouri     |Wal-MartStore|
|724 STADIUM WEST BLVD     |Jefferson City|Missouri     |SuperCenter  |
|701 WALTON DRIVE          |Farmington    |Missouri     |SuperCenter  |
|2025 BUS. HWY 60 WEST     |Dexter        |Missouri     |SuperCenter  |
|2250 LINCOLN AVENUE       |Nevada        |Missouri     |SuperCenter  |
|1301 HWY 24 EAST          |Moberly       |Missouri     |SuperCenter  |
|1802 SOUTH BUSINESS HWY 54|Eldon         |Missouri     |Wal-MartStore|
|3450 S. 4TH TRAFFICWAY    |Leavenworth   |Kansas       |Wal-MartStore|
|101 EAST BLUEMONT AVENUE  |Manhattan     |Kansas       |SuperCenter  |
|2400 SOUTH MAIN           |Fort Scott    |Kansas       |Wal-MartStore|
+--------------------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: thank you , and spark sql commands are not working in my cmd, for example  spark.sql("select * from table ") this is not working but        joinDf.select("name").show its working i dont whta the resaon behind it . can u please answer for it also

Comment: @uppalaadarsh man, please proof read your text before submitting it. It's really hard to read. And if you want to use SQL in Spark you have to register the Dataframes as SQL tables first, otherwise, how should Spark know to what the name `table` refers to among all the Dataframes?

Comment: if you are okay please care to accept [the answer as owner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/369717) and [vote-up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/369717)